# Why it takes me a long time to compile this simple C code?

Tags: c, compilation

Why does it take so long (around 10 ~ 20 sec.) to compile my simple printf code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    printf("why am i so slow\n");
}
```

This is the output I got in VSCode terminal:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Gnij\cs50_classes\" && gcc pset_hello.c -o pset_hello && "c:\Users\Gnij\cs50_classes\"pset_hello
why am I so slow

[Done] exited with code=0 in 19.531 seconds
```

```
Windows 11
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Compiler: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
```

I expected this to be done in less than five seconds.
However, when I was executing the .exe file of this program, it ran instantly. Why is this the case?

Comment: Hard to say. I compile it in 0.02 seconds.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus active? In this case disable it temporally and test again ...

Comment: It would take _me_ much longer than 10-20 seconds to compile that.  I usually cheat and use a program to do it.  ;)